# Attempt to turn all the switches on or off

Tags: logical-deduction

Here is the puzzle for you. There are four boxes in front of you arranged in a circle. Inside each box is a switch that is on or off. You cannot see inside the boxes. Each turn you stick your hands into two boxes of your choice and then choose to flip any number of them. You do not feel whether or not the switches you touched were on or off. After this, the boxes rotate until you do not remember or know which boxes you put your hands in before or anything like that. You win if all the switches are on or off. How can you guarantee a victory?
Edit: I didn't make this puzzle and a friend told it to me

Comment: If all the switches are on or off at any time, then you win

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: is that proper attribution?

Comment: Hearsay is valid yes, but if you have any way to know where the puzzle is truly from (or if your friend made it), it would be even better.

Comment: I don't know where he got it

Comment: It's a similar question, but I don't think so. Plus, I already know the answer to the puzzle I gave.

Comment: The [Sliding bolt puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43/sliding-bolt-puzzle) is equivalent.

Comment: Oh. That's ok. Seems to be the same